# How do I get particular users role in WSO2 api store/publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

In my WSO2 api store instance, I want to make some modification so that I can allow some actions only to Admin and not to normal Publiser/Subscriber. For instance, if I want to restring other users from editing my published APIs, and only Admin role should be given privilege to modify any API. For this, how can I get the users role?

I tried to get Roles from carbon module

**/modules/carbon/scripts/user/user.js**

```
  User.prototype.getRoles = function () {
        return this.um.manager.getRoleListOfUser(this.username);
    };

    User.prototype.hasRoles = function (roles) {
        var i, j, role,
            rs = this.getRoles(),
            length1 = roles.length,
            length2 = rs.length;
        L1:
            for (i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
                //Array.indexOf() fails due to Java String vs JS String difference
                role = roles[i];
                for (j = 0; j < length2; j++) {
                    if (role == rs[j]) {
                        continue L1;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        return true;
    };
```

But was unsuccessful to invoke this method. Anybody have an idea how to get the role of a logged in user, or how to check whether the logged in user is an admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by assigning the required roles to users, have a look into [Adding User Roles](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Adding+User+Roles)

Or

You could use WSO2 API Manager's Publisher API ["Validate Roles"](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Publisher+APIs#PublisherAPIs-ValidateRoles) tr retrieve the roles of the logged in user.

```
Description :
      Check if the user logged in user is any one in a given list of users
URI :
      http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag
URI Parameters :    
      action=validateRoles&roles=<list of roles>
HTTP Methods    :
      GET
Example :
      curl -b cookies "http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag?action=validateRoles&roles=admin"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Checked with Validate roles, but it is returning {response: true} for all roles.  
For example I have an admin user, who has admin role. When I validate role using API, it is returning true. I have another user say "test" and with role 'Internal/everyone' when I validate this user for 'admin' role, I'm getting the same response true, even though this user is not an admin
It is not validating the current users role.

Comment: What was your exact response, please add it here. Have you used credintial to login first?

Comment: For admin user

http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag?action=validateRoles&roles=admin

Response

{"error" : false, "response" : true}

For another user who is not an admin response is same.

Comment: yes,, first used login api and then validate role api

Comment: No, I tested locally, It works fine, Check whether that user has admin role or not.

Comment: yes, validateRoles api wil tell us that whether the logged in user is any one in a given list of roles, but I want to differentiate admin. I want to know whether the logged in user is an admin or not. Like we can check the logged in user has a publisher role with hasPublisherRole api call.